# How do i use check constraints?

Tags: sql, t-sql

How do i use check constraints?

```
create table tblCourseMaster
(
course_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
course_code varchar(10)not null,
course_name varchar(50),
course_duration int check(course_ duration>0 and course_duration <6)
)
```

I got following error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'duration'.

Answer (score 2):

```
create table tblCourseMaster 
( 
  course_id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
  course_code varchar(10) not null, 
  course_name varchar(50), 
  course_duration int check(course_duration > 0 and course_duration < 6) 
)
```

Change `varchaar` to `varchar` and `course_ duration` to `course_duration`.